# Pay Transparency Law broken by company that hired me in Connecticut. Any recourse?

Tags: employment, connecticut

### Short Version

Applied to a company, got hired for a below average salary for my profession, realized they broke a law by not disclosing the salary range for the position. Can I do anything about it?

### Long Version

I applied to job about 3 months ago at a large (200+) company in Connecticut. In the job description on Indeed, they failed to disclose the salary range as required in [Connecticut HB 6380](https://www.cga.ct.gov/2021/ACT/PA/PDF/2021PA-00030-R00HB-06380-PA.PDF).

At the time, I had been unemployed for several months and was desperate to get a paycheck for my family, so I didn't care to bring this up. After a few interview rounds, I asked what the salary range was, and didn't get a response.

During the last interview, the HR hiring manager asked what my salary requirements were. Again, I was desperate, and at this point quite nervous. They told me it was between myself and another candidate, so I felt pressured to say a lower salary than I should have.

The offer letter came a few days later with the salary being the lowest end of the range I gave.

Now I'm on the team, and I really enjoy it. However, the whole salary negotiation (if you can call it that) left a bad taste in my mouth. I feel like I got taken for a ride, and now I make less than I should.

Is there any legal course of action I can take at this point to increase my salary? Preferably without jeopardizing my job.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any legal course of action I can take at this point to increase my salary?

The law seems to say you can be compensated by a court.  It gives no guidance to the court, so it could be $1 to many thousands of dollars, plus attorney's fees.  It does not mention raising your actual salary.

> Preferably without jeopardizing my job.

Not so fast, my friend!  Suing your employer is unlikely to be a long-term winning strategy.  These strategies are better for those who have other employment options or no longer work for the company.